# Can I use ng-include element to add my Google Analytics script?

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, angularjs-ng-include

I have a partials/google-analytics.html and I would like to use ng-include to organize it.

**index.html**

```
<ng-include src="'partials/google-analytics.html'"></ng-include>
```

**partials/google-analytics.html**

```
<script>
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Does it work?

Comment: What are you trying to gain by using ng-include over a standard script tag?

Answer (score 0):

It will probably work, but its not ideal.  GA suggests putting the code in the `<head>` before the closing `</head>`.  This is to ensure it is loaded and evaluated before the user interacts with anything on your page.  If you put it in a separate `<ng-include>`, that file will be loaded asynchronously and you run the risk of missing events.